# How to turn a string into an array of strings?

Tags: java, parsing, split

For example, I want a string `"1:00 pm 2:00 pm 3:00 pm"` to turn into an array of a string of `["1:00 pm", "2:00 pm", "3:00 pm"]`

I've tried using split. But it would produce `["1:00", "pm", "2:00", "pm", "3:00", "pm"]`. How would I split every other space? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` using regular expression, Regular expression `(?<=m)` to split the string using `m` as delimiter  and including it. But there will be extra empty character from second element you can use `trim()` method to remove it

```
String s =  "1:00 pm 2:00 pm 3:00 pm";

String[] arr = s.split("(?<=m)");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));   //[1:00 pm,  2:00 pm,  3:00 pm]
```

Comment: This works but I don't really understand how. Thank you

Comment: You just need to familiar  with regular expressions 
@TruongNguyen  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 2):

For your problem I might suggest using a formal Java regex matcher.  The reason for this is that perhaps your time strings could appear as part of a larger string.

```
String input = "1:00 pm 2:00 pm 3:00 pm";
String pattern = "(?i)\\d{1,2}:\\d{2} [ap]m";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
     System.out.println("Found a time: " + m.group(0));
}
```

This prints:

```
Found a time: 1:00 pm
Found a time: 2:00 pm
Found a time: 3:00 pm
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Java's indexOf method to find the index of each space and only take into account every other one. Then, create a sub string using your knowledge of the spaces and add it to your array.